# MOSS Standard drop down menu

Tags: sharepoint-2007

How do I make MOSS Standard drop down menu to by open right to left

Comment: which standard drop down menu ?

Answer (score 0):

This page suggests that you need to set the site locale to be a language that has right to left text:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2006/12/02/customizing-the-wss-3-0-moss-2007-menu-control-mossmenu-source-code-released.aspx

But:

> In right-to-left locales, the fly-out
>   indicator arrow still points from
>   left-to-right.

And from this page, i guess that is Arabic or Hebrew

http://forums.asp.net/t/1097435.aspx